# Aspose-Cells: Autofilter on worksheet with more then 26 columns

Tags: vb.net, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm in kind of a bind here. I need to set an autofilter on a worksheet. To do this I normally use the following code:

Here `Columncount` is the number of columns `visible`

```
Dim alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
myDatasheet.AutoFilter.Range = (String.Format("A1:{0}1", alphabet.Substring(columnCount - 1, 1)))
```

This works up until 26 columns (which is normal as the alphabet is 26 letters long). But suddenly I have 29 columns `(Columncount = 29)`. which causes `argumentoutofrangeexception`.

**Question:** Any idea how I can modify the code to make work on 26 or more columns?

**Note:** I did my research mainly on the aspose site, but no info or examples found in case of more then 26 columns

[AutoFilter Class: Aspose.cells](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/AutoFilter+Class)

[Aspose: Autofilter data](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Auto+Filter+Data)

[Aspose-Cells: Data Filtering](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Data+Filtering+and+Validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually instead of posting here, I should have thought this more through. The solution in fact is quite simple using MOD-calculation:

```
Dim alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Dim lastString As String = String.Empty

Dim isDoubledletters As Boolean = (CInt(columnCount / alphabet.Length) > 0)
If Not (isDoubledletters) Then
     myDatasheet.AutoFilter.Range = (String.Format("A1:{0}1", alphabet.Substring(columnCount - 1, 1)))
Else
     Dim myEndFilter As String = alphabet.ToCharArray()(CInt(columnCount / alphabet.Length) - 1).ToString &
     alphabet.ToCharArray()(CInt(columnCount Mod alphabet.Length) - 1).ToString
                myDatasheet.AutoFilter.Range = (String.Format("A1:{0}1", myEndFilter))
End If
```

Hope this may be of some use to anyone in the future